# Why does this one PAnsiChar get chopped when converted to AnsiString?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe3

Please consider the following program:

```
program SO41175184;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function Int9999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(9999)));
end;

function Int99999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(99999)));
end;

function Int999999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(999999)));
end;

function Str9999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString('9999'));
end;

function Str99999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString('99999'));
end;

function Str999999: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString('999999'));
end;

begin
  WriteLn(Int9999); // '9999'
  WriteLn(Int99999); // '99999'
  WriteLn(Int999999); // '999999'

  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Str9999))); // '9999'
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Str99999))); // '99999'
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Str999999))); // '999999'

  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(9999)))))); // '9999'
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(99999)))))); // '99999'
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(999999)))))); // '999999'

  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Int9999))); // '9999'
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Int99999))); // '9999' <----- ?!
  WriteLn(string(AnsiString(Int999999))); // '999999'

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Only in one of these cases does the string lose a single character, in Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE3 both. With FPC the same program works correctly. Switching to `PChar` also makes the problem disappear.

I suppose it has something to do with memory management, but I don't have enough of a clue where to look to do a meaningful investigation. Could anyone clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamically created strings are reference counted and deallocated when no references remain.

```
Result := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(IntToStr(99999)));
```

causes a temporary `AnsiString` to be created, its address taken via the cast to `PAnsiChar`, and then the temporary string deallocated<sup>†</sup>. The resulting pointer points to now-unclaimed memory that may be overwritten for pretty much any reason, including during the allocations of more strings.

Neither Delphi nor FPC clears memory by default during deallocations, so if the memory hasn't been re-used yet, you may get lucky when reading what used to be there. Or, as you saw, you may not.

When returning `PAnsiChar` like this, you need an agreement between caller and callee on memory management. You need to make sure you do not free the memory early, *and* you need to make sure your callers know how to free the memory afterwards.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Remy Lebeau points out that this deallocation happens when the procedure or function returns. If there is another statement after the assignment to `Result`, the string will still be available. This is normally correct, but there are also cases where it the temporary string gets deallocated before the return, for example when you create temporary strings in a loop. I would not recommend using temporary objects after the statement that creates them concludes, even in cases where it is valid, because it makes it too hard to verify whether the code is correct. For those cases, just use an explicit variable.</sub>

Comment: I can understand that reasoning, but still I find it curious how it only occurs for one of these values. It's happening in my sample program exactly the same way it did in the program I'm debugging. I'd expect it to sometimes work and sometimes not, for example. What would explain this consistency and the difference between values?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien The allocator is hard to predict but fairly deterministic. If it behaves a certain way in one execution of your program, there's a good chance it'll behave that way in all executions. One additional point is that the length of '9999' is a trivial multiple of 4. Memory blocks are usually aligned to 4-byte boundaries, so that explains why a partial overwrite happens to overwrite the fifth character.

Comment: @Remy Words that do not start a sentence should not be capitalised. Functions that return pointers should worry about all callers, so that should remain plural. Your note about specifically when the deallocation happens was a good one and I'll try to bring that back in when I can do a little extra testing.

Comment: @Thijs: It is undocumented behaviour, so anything can happen, You were just ***lucky*** that the other function calls displayed what you expected. The behaviour is undefined, but not wholly undetermined. It simply depends on how the same memory manager manages the same order of allocation and deallocation, even on different systems. This could be different with a different version of the compiler or a different memory manager.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien - try turning a random behavior into deterministic. 1) update Delphi Memory Manager to the latest version from https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4 2) use that updated unit as the first unit of your test project 3) within FastMM4Options.inc enable the {.$define AlwaysClearFreedMemory} option 4) build your project and see how it works now, that using content after free got prohibited

Comment: @Arioch'The: The behaviour is not really random. The exact same machine code (which does not depend on anything random) will very likely produce the exact same result, again and again. It is undefined behaviour, but not necessarily random.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added a footnote about the precise moment of destruction of temporary objects, does that look right to you?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It won't be repeatable because the environment will likely differ. For instance, one execution, VirtualAlloc will give you contiguous blocks, the next execution they will be discontinuous.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Since this code does not depend on the environment (except things like the block size returned by VirtualAlloc, but that influence is pretty small for such a small block), chances are very big that the outcome will be exactly the same in a different environment, as long as the same compiler+runtime+target platform+memory manager are used.

Comment: @David: not very much. So in most circumstances/environments, the outcome will be exactly the same. Not in all, but most definitely in most.

Comment: It's a bit of a silly argument but imagine one run when two calls to VirtualAlloc return adjacent blocks and the next run where the blocks are disjoint. Overrun the first buffer in the first run and its a heap corruption. In the second run it's an AV. Anyway, it's not very interesting to argue about UB.

Comment: @Arioch'The That's very helpful advice! Heard a lot about FastMM4 being great and stuff, but now I have a sample use case and a starting point for similar problems in the future.

Comment: Actually Delphi uses stripped down FastMM4 fork. But since RTL is pre-compiled there is no way to enable those options, like this ClearOnFree, and we need a stand-alone full FadtMM4